# Como passar um valor do AngularJS para o controller do JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

Tenho um formulario que envia um valor(CPF) de uma página para ser verificado quanto a existencia na base de dados. Uso um controller angular para enviar o cpf para service e depois para o Java(controller).

Teria algum exemplo de como fazer isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código HTML**

```
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cpf" class="">CPF:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" ng-model="cpf" >
      </div>

      <button ng-click="buscarCliente()">Buscar Cliente</button>

   </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Código Controller**

```
angular.module('').controller('TesteController', function ($scope, $timeout, MensagemFactory, ) {

var vm = $scope;

vm.buscarCliente = function(){
      if (vm.cpf != NULL) {
        alert("!");
  }
};
```

}

**Código Services**

```
angular.module('').service('Service', function (servers) {

    var service = {
      getCpf: getCpf
    };

    function getCpf(){
      return $http.get(servers.vendas + 'api/buscarCliente');
    }

    return service;
  });
```

**Codigo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/alexjosesilva/d48syn5c/

Comment: Favor reescrever sua pergunta, atentando para os erros de português e concordância.

Comment: Qual o código que você já tem ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alexjosesilva/d48syn5c/

Comment: Nessa série de vídeo aulas do Diogo Godoi ele desenvolve uma aplicação JavaEE com AngularJS explicando passo a passo comunicação entre cliente e servidor. CRUD completo com comunicação também com bando de dados, muito bom a serie, recomendo fortemente. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1NdiP2jsLnuEqNkOF7-ISTciRrKd51Hv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde Alex,

Algo que notei no seu código é que você está chamando sua função por um ng-click mesmo possuindo um formulário, sugiro fazer sua requisição no submit do mesmo. Se entendi bem o que você quis dizer, vou lhe passar um exemplo:

```
var _SeuServico = ['$http', function($http) {


    function _getCpf() {
        return $http.get(servers.vendas + 'api/buscarCliente');
    }

    return {
        getCpf: _getCpf,
    };
}]; 

angular.module('').factory('SeuServico', _SeuServico);
```

Já para seu controller você injetaria o seu serviço e faria a chamada desta forma:

```
    SeuServico.getCpf().then(function(_data) {
        //Seu codigo
    });
```

Dependendo do seu serviço recomendo que dê uma olhada nas promises do angular.

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q